# Connect a Flutter app to a MySQL database that's on a VM

Tags: mysql, flutter

For a school project, we want to create an app using flutter (dart + android studio), and for it we would need a database to which we connect the app.
We have two options :

- A MySQL database that's hosted on our school's servers (on a Ubuntu VM, accessible from SSH with a host address, username an password)
- Another MySQL database on our school's server, but hosted directly on a server for databases (no VM). For that one, we would have more 'common' logs as the **host and port.**

Here are the specs of the second one :

> Linux Fedora Core 18 //
> Apache/2.4.4 PHP/5.4.14 //
> MySQL Community Server (GPL) 5.5.31 //
> phpMyAdmin 3.5.8.1 (2013-04-24)

My question is, how can I access these sql databases (ideally using the second method) from my flutter app ? I know there's a way to access local MySQL databases from flutter, but as the base will be hosted on an external server, I don't know how to correctly connect and dialogue with it.

Thanks

Comment: flutter has mysql package name mysql1 .but it is not stable i think.you can use postgresql and it well maintainer.if you want myslq as mention here you need to make api accessing the mysql and host on your server then access that api in flutter

Comment: if you want to use only in android  you can use mysql driver and using method channel you can access your mysql data from android side to flutter

Comment: Since flutter is actually compiled as javaScript (for Android,iOS and web), you need to work as if you would work with HTML5 project , and since MySQL is usually installed on Linux along with PHP, im my opinion it's the best way to get the data from the database, This is how I worked to create a flutter based application for projects based on MySQL database.

Comment: @lava Thanks, I'll look into how to build an API

Comment: @YahalomSoftware Thanks, thing is I never did any HTML project haha

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The `mysql1` package is not well maintained. Google Dart developers do not provide built-in support of RDBMS.

There is another package to work with mysql, maybe you can take a look. [mysql_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql_client)

I think that the best solution is to create a restApi on your server to manage your crud operation with the mysql database. There are a lot of tutorials on how to create a node application that lives in your server and interact with your database.

This is also a good solution because you add a layer that manage all the back-end stuff of your application.

Comment: Hey, thanks.

I never worked with API's, so if i understand, i create one on my VM, and there is a way to connect my flutter app to the API even if I'm not on the same server as the VM ?

Comment: You need to create the restAPI on the server. Watch a tutorial on node server restAPI